# How to use `fmt` in query with mysql

Tags: mysql, go

I use fmt to create two field in my_table.

```
const   (
    SELECT_ALL_USERID = "select user_id from notification_settings where ? = 1 and ? = 1 and frequency = ? and is_holiday = ?"
)

func (user_station) GetAllUserId(db *gorp.DbMap,isLine string ,isHourClock int ,frequency , isHoliday string) ([]models.UserID,error) {
    var listUserId []models.UserID
    var is_line = fmt.Sprintf("is_%s",isLine)
    var is_hour_oclock = fmt.Sprintf("is_%d_oclock",isHourClock)
    _,err := db.Select(&listUserId,SELECT_ALL_USERID,is_line,is_hour_oclock,frequency,isHoliday)
    return listUserId,err
}
```

So, I tried `?` in WHERE CLAUSE but it fail . What i am missing ?

Comment: `I use fmt to create two field in my_table.` Doctor Normal would consider this a strange thing to do

Comment: my field always change when call API .So , i use fmt  . it like : is_1_oclock, is_2_oclock .....is_24_oclock.

Comment: This is strongly suggestive of poor schema design

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `?` to bind column names, only values. Instead, build your query string using fmt:

```
select_all_userid:=fmt.Sprintf("select user_id from notification_settings where is_%s = 1 and is_%s_oclock = 1 and frequency = ? and is_holiday = ?",isLine,isHourClock)
```